# Angular2/Typescript returns 404 not found when trying to import css-animator

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-directives, polyfills

I just started to play with angular2 and trying to do some animations with [css-animator](https://github.com/fabiandev/css-animator)

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/forms": "0.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.7",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.12",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "chokidar": "^1.6.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "css-animator": "^1.2.4",
    "http-proxy": "^1.14.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
 }
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/bootstrap.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/style.css">
   <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
 <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
   <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
   <script src="node_modules/css-animator/builder/animation_builder.js">      </script>
   <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
   <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
   <script>
     System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
   </script>
         </head>
     <!-- 3. Display the application -->
        <body class="bg-image">
          <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
          </body>
      </html>
```

**systemjs.config.js**

```
var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',

    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    'css-animator':               'node_modules/css-animator'
  };
   var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'   },
     };
     System.config(config);
```

**custom.animate.directive.ts**

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Renderer} from '@angular/core';
 import {AnimationService, AnimationBuilder} from 'css-animator';

 @Directive({
    selector: '[login-method]',
    host: {
      '(click)':'onClick()'
   }
})

export class LoginOptionsDirective{
   private animator : AnimationBuilder;

   constructor(animationService: AnimationService, private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer){
      this.animator = animationService.builder();
  }

  onclick(){
      this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el, 'color','black');
      console.log(this.el.nativeElement.getAttribute("login-method"));
   }
 }
```

I got `animation_builder.js:434 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined` and `localhost/:18 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/css-animator(…)` on browser console.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe rc3 is nonexistent. Change your dependency versions to "rc.2"

Comment: rc3 is the latest version release last June 21, 2016 according to https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are including `animation_builder.js` directly in the `<head>` section:

```
<script src="node_modules/css-animator/builder/animation_builder.js"></script>
```

You get a ReferenceError, because the single files included in the [css-animator](https://github.com/fabiandev/css-animator) package are compiled to CommonJS, which the browser doesn't understand natively.

Try removing that line, and SystemJS should load the files automatically, if you import them somewhere. Also SystemJS understands CommonJS.

Alternatively, you could include the SystemJS bundle provided by the package in the `<head>` section. If you then import a module from css-animator, SystemJS has this module already registered and can load it instantly.

You may include the minified or unminified bundle like this:

```
<!-- Unminified Source -->
<script src="node_modules/css-animator/bundles/css-animator.js"></script>

<!-- Minified Source -->
<script src="node_modules/css-animator/bundles/css-animator.min.js"></script>
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this package.

Comment: `animation_builder.js:434 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined` is solved but I still have an error `zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/css-animator/ 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: I think you have to tell SystemJS what the main entry point to `css-animator` is. Try to add `'css-animator': { main: 'index.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },` to the `packages` object. If you have time, you may want to look into [jspm](http://jspm.io) for your front-end dependency management. It generates the SystemJS config file for you.

Comment: thanks it work.. I had to add 'css-animator': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' } in my packages.